# reset all cells to turn white using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to alert "bingo" and reset the cells to white when three boxes are gray.  So I did a sample of only doing "square0","square1","square2", which alerts "Bingo", but it does not reset all the cells back to white.

http://jsfiddle.net/d5x5qxp5/20/

HTML5:

```
<table class="bingo">
   <tr>
        <td id="square0"></td>
        <td id="square1"></td>
        <td id="square2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td id="square3"></td>
        <td id="square4"></td>
        <td id="square5"></td>

</tr>
<tr>
        <td id="square6"></td>
        <td id="square7"></td>
        <td id="square8"></td>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
/* declare variables: get tag from html */
var $ = function (id) {
   return document.getElementById(id); 
}

// cell is parameter
var toggleHighlight = function (cell) {
var bg = cell.target.style.backgroundColor;
if (bg == "rgb(206, 206, 206)") {
    cell.target.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
         } else {
    cell.target.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(206, 206, 206)";   
    }
   }

// alert Bingo and reset cells to white
var bingo = function(cell) {
    if ($("square0").style.backgroundColor == "rgb(206, 206, 206)" &&             $("square1").style.backgroundColor == "rgb(206, 206, 206)" && $("square2").style.backgroundColor == "rgb(206, 206, 206)" ) {
 alert ("Bingo!!");
 cell.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
 }
} 


// getting a list from "td" will return a list, it is needed for a loop to store the cells 
var storeCells = function () { 
  var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (var i = 0 ; i < cells.length ; i++) {
        cells[i].onclick = function(event) {
            toggleHighlight(event); // event is argument
            bingo(cells);  
        }
    }
  }


var rLetter = function (rL) {
// randomLetters 
var rL = Math.floor((Math.random() * 31) + 1);

Math.floor((Math.random() * 31) + 1);


if (rL== 1) {
 return rL = "A";
} else if (rL == 2) {
 return rL = "B";
} else if (rL == 3) {
 return rL = "C"
} else if (rL == 5) {
 return rL = "D";
} else if (rL == 6) {
 return rL = "E";
} else if (rL == 7) {
 return rL = "F";
} else if (rL == 8) {
 return rL = "G";
} else if (rL == 9) {
 return rL = "H";
} else if (rL == 10) {
 return rL = "I";
} else if (rL == 11) {
 return rL = "J";
} else if (rL == 12) {
 return rL = "G";
} else if (rL == 13) {
 return rL = "H";
} else if (rL == 14) {
 return rL = "I";
} else if (rL == 15) {
 return rL = "J";   
} else if (rL == 16) {
 return rL = "K";
} else if (rL == 17) {
 return rL = "L";
} else if (rL == 18) {
 return rL = "M";
} else if (rL == 19) {
 return rL = "N";   
} else if (rL == 20) {
 return rL = "O";
} else if (rL == 21) {
 return rL = "P";
} else if (rL == 22) {
 return rL = "Q";
} else if (rL == 23) {
 return rL = "R";
} else if (rL == 24) {
 return rL = "S";
} else if (rL == 25) {
 return rL = "T";   
} else if (rL == 26) {
 return rL = "U";   
} else if (rL == 27) {
 return rL = "V";
} else if (rL == 28) {
 return rL = "W";   
} else if (rL == 29) {
 return rL = "X";
} else if (rL == 30) {
 return rL = "Y";
} else {
 return rL = "Z";
}
};

window.onload = function () {

//calls the function
storeCells();

$("square0").innerHTML = rLetter(1);
$("square1").innerHTML = rLetter(2);
$("square2").innerHTML = rLetter(3);
$("square3").innerHTML = rLetter(4);
$("square4").innerHTML = rLetter(5);
$("square5").innerHTML = rLetter(6);
$("square6").innerHTML = rLetter(7);
$("square7").innerHTML = rLetter(8);
$("square8").innerHTML = rLetter(9);    

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this code to your javascript code. Call this "reset()" function after the "Bingo" alert.

```
var reset = function() {
    var tdElements = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for(var i in tdElements){
        if(typeof tdElements[i].style != 'undefined') {
            tdElements[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you call bingo() function "cells" parameter contain all "td" elements, so you need to loop the elements and find out gray cells & change its color to white

```
var bingo = function(cell) {
    if ($("square0").style.backgroundColor == "rgb(206, 206, 206)" && $("square1").style.backgroundColor == "rgb(206, 206, 206)" && $("square2").style.backgroundColor == "rgb(206, 206, 206)" ) {
        alert ("Bingo!!");
        //loop through all td elements
        for(var i=0; i < cell.length; i++){
            //only change color if it is gray cell
            if(cell[i].style.backgroundColor == "rgb(206, 206, 206)"){
                cell[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/5acjr04y/